# Select the option using the value from a SESSION, not working

Tags: php

I'm trying to give the selected attribute to the year that is stored in a SESSION ( in the script I posted the date 1990-06-27 is the SESSION I'm talking about ). Everything goes well for $month but when I do the same If statement for $year is not working and I really have no idea why.

```
list($y,$m,$d)=explode('-', "1990-06-27");     
for($month=1; $month<=12; $month++) {
    $monthName = date("F", mktime(0, 0, 0, $month));
    $month = date("m", mktime(0, 0, 0, $month));
    $luni = array ('January' => 'Ianuarie', 'February' => 'Februarie', 'March' =>     'Martie', 'April' => 'Aprilie', 'May' => 'Mai', 'June' => 'Iunie', 'July' => 'Iulie', 'August' => 'August', 'September' => 'Septembrie', 'October' => 'Octombrie', 'November' => 'Noiembrie', 'December' => 'Decembrie');
        If($m === $month) { 
            $selected = 'selected="selected"';
            $monthOptions .= "<option value=\"{$month}\" $selected>{$luni[$monthName]}</option>\n";
        } else {
            $monthOptions .= "<option value=\"{$month}\">{$luni[$monthName]}</option>\n";
        }
}

$an_curent = date("Y", time());
for($year = $an_curent - 80; $year <= $an_curent - 16; $year++) {
    If($y === $year) { 
        $selected = 'selected="selected"';
        $yearOptions .= "<option value=\"{$year}\" $selected>{$year}</option>\n";  
    } else {
        $yearOptions .= "<option value=\"{$year}\">{$year}</option>\n";  
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`$year` is an integer, whereas `$y` is a string. 
Therefore, the `===` operator always returns false. 
Using `==` should fix this.